# how to solve it so that when you click the button the box will hover like loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Previously, I have added hover and transition styles to the box. Well, then I thought of trying to add a button which when clicked would be the same as on hover without hovering the pointer over the box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PukwL.png)

Comment: please include your code as text for someone to better address your problem

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no examples of your code, I will just give basic example.

You will need to create a function, something like this

```
 var element = document.getElementById("IdOfYourElement").style.color;
 function changeColor(){
  element = "blue"; // example 
 }
```

And then, just call the function on your button, by adding

```
 onClick = "changeColor()"
```